# how to get search results from string to echo variable

Tags: php

I am trying to search a string with more then one term and if found then the relative term will be echo to a variable that i can use, at the moment it just echos the last category regardless of what it finds:

```
//Page info

$PageTitle = "audio";

$search_for = array('Electrical Serviceh' => 'electrical, audio, electrician, security', 'Plumbing Servicey' => 'heating, gas');
foreach ($search_for as $name=>$term){
 if (strpos($PageTitle,$term) !== false){
 echo $name;

 }
}

echo $name;
```

need to be able to use the outputted variable anywhere on page by echoing it.

Comment: If you're always echoing out the last category, doesn't that mean strpos isn't returning false? Therefore it's found the `$PageTitle` in the `$term`.  Maybe you should echo out the page title to see if you're always passing in the same thing to that foreach loop.

Comment: tried it in its basic form, it should output "electrical serviceh"

Comment: @david I tried it and it output nothing at all, telling me the strpos() was always false. So I tried putting the whole string "electrical, audio, electrician, security" in $PageTitle and it worked as expected. This is telling me that the foreach isn't breaking the search terms down to individual parts.

Comment: made a fiddle: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZgSpWy

Comment: is there a better way of doing this

Comment: @david The thing is, you need to write the code. I can tell you that between the array definition and the foreach statement something is broken. This isn't a bad way to do it and I'm sure you could make it work, but you have to write it.

Comment: @david  see below. I had a few minutes free to play with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71362/discussion-between-bigscar-and-david).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work. I redefined the array and added a second foreach loop

```
    <?php
    //Page info
    $PageTitle = "Johnson electrician";
    $search_for =
    array('Electrical Serviceh' => array('electrical', 'audio', 'electrician', 'security'), 'Plumbing Servicey' => array('heating', 'gas'));
    foreach ($search_for as $name=>$term){
         foreach ($term as $findme)
         {
             if (strpos($PageTitle,$findme) !== false)
             {
             echo $name;
             }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: your amazing BigScar been beating away at this all night, just came back to your post thank you. Well done. just opened up a world of understanding and possibilities for me, cant thank you enough

Comment: trying to do one last thing which worked in my last step with single values: http://codepad.viper-7.com/vowaKO, but now you can enter multiple values you get all results when you echo it directly: http://codepad.viper-7.com/38sRBX . So i tried doing the same with your new code so it outputs to a variable i can use buts fails: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9b4q3t