# strpos not searching string from array data

Tags: php

Want to get the an outputted variable that I can echo anywhere, from this statement. It need to check the value of $PageTitle then output the correct value into a variable:

//Page info

```
$PageTitle = "audio";

//Body header menu
$search_for = array('Electrical Service' => 'electrical, electrician, security, audio, video', 'Plumbing Service' => 'heating, gas', 'water' => 'water');

foreach ($search_for as $name=>$term){
 if (strpos($PageTitle,$term) !== false){
  echo $name;
  // add break; here if you want to display only one (first) found
 }
}

//need to echo result anywhere on page
echo $name;
```

FIDDLE:  http://codepad.viper-7.com/FAelDG

It outputs "water" instead of "Electrical serviceh"

Answered by BigScar in a very beautiful and elegant way well done.

[how to get search results from string to echo variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633803/how-to-get-search-results-from-string-to-echo-variable?noredirect=1#comment45575529_28633803)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `strpos()` wrong. If you look into the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

And take a quote from there:

> mixed strpos ( string **$haystack** , mixed **$needle** [, int $offset = 0 ] )

So you have to change the order of your arguments, e.g:

```
if (strpos($term, $PageTitle) !== false){
         //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Changed
```

Comment: does the "mixed strpos" solve the problem with the fact if the variable contains any other word in it, it does not work, eg. $PageTitle="audio video";

Comment: @david It doesn't match, because it has to be an exact match and in the haystack there is a comma in the string

Comment: is there another way of doing it where it can find a keyword in a sentence then give it a category.

Comment: @david I don't really see what your goal is now?

Comment: i just did that in a basic way  to get it working, Still want to achieve the same thing, but the variable will contain more the one word, and for other uses even a sentence. So if a keyword is found within a group of words with the variable eg. $PageTitle="lots of words and also the keyword audio";  then it should echo a name eg." Electrical service".

Comment: @david Then I think you want to split this variable into an array (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) And go through each word to see if it is in the other array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71360/discussion-between-david-and-rizier123).

Comment: BigScar did it. great code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633803/how-to-get-search-results-from-string-to-echo-variable?noredirect=1#comment45575529_28633803

Answer (score 3):

You have the arguments to [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) the wrong way around. It should be:

```
if (strpos($term,$PageTitle) !== false){
```

Take a look at the function signature: haystack, needle, not needle, haystack

> mixed strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )

[Updated demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/a9jcDS) - outputs `Electrical Service`.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/vowaKO - great thank you only thing is it must be pure, If the $PageTitle contains any other words it fails, for example $PageTitle ="audio video"; it wont match.

Comment: even a space, throws out the search

Comment: That's how `strpos` is designed to work. I think you need to decide exactly what your requirements are, and look at alternate solution.